# Tilting problem in Unity

Tags: unity

I want to tilt my object left or right depending on which side I'm moving my mouse. I wrote something like that:

```
    if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") > 1) {
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, (-35 * Time.deltaTime * speed));
    }
    else if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") < -1) {
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, (35 * Time.deltaTime * speed));
    }
    else if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") == 0) {
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
    }
```

It's working only when I move mouse very fast and it's not 'smooth'. Would be thankful if anyone would help me :)

Comment: Why are you multiplying by deltaTime here? You want to tilt less at high framerates than at low framerates?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using a class member in order to save the euler angles between the frames. Then, according to the input, just change a little bit the angles, and assign the new computed rotation.

```
private Vector3 eulerAngles;

[SerializeField]
private float tiltSpeed = 50;

[SerializeField]
private float recenterSpeed = 20;

void Update()
{
    float offset = tiltSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") > 0f)
    {
        eulerAngles.z -= offset;
    }
    else if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") < -0f)
    {
        eulerAngles.z += offset;
    }
    else
    {
        offset = recenterSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if( Mathf.Abs(offset) > Mathf.Abs(eulerAngles.z) )
            eulerAngles.z = 0 ;
        else
            eulerAngles.z -= offset * Mathf.Sign( eulerAngles.z );
    }

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(eulerAngles);
}
```